# Jhipster Hot Reload Crashes Node

Tags: node.js, jhipster, livereload

I isolated a problem I am facing to these simple steps:

I generate new JHipster project accepting all default selections.

Then I run:

*npm start*

Th browser opens successfully, although backend is not up.

I open ./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.html in an editor and add simple "Hello World" after the last generated  as following:

If you like JHipster, don't forget to give us a star on GitHub!


*Hello World!*

When I save the file, the page refreshes automatically on the browser. Second or third-time doing simple change and saving it does not refresh the browser and node process takes over the processor, almost 100%. Waiting for it for a long time has no impact and I have to kill the node process. Sometimes it crashes even with the first change/save cycle.

I am using Apple MAC 10.13.6, JHipster 5.5.0, npm version 6.4.1. Node version v11.0.0. I have 16 Giga of RAM.

Comment: Which node version? Do you have enough RAM?

Comment: Node version v11.0.0. I have 16 Giga of RAM. I added this information to the question.

Comment: Node 11 is not an LTS version, we recommend using an LTS 64 bit version here: https://www.jhipster.tech/installation/

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. 

Answer (score 1):

I just uninstalled node and installed node LTS v10.13.0 and the issue is fixed.

It is stated that Jhipster is supporting node LTS only at this link jhipster.tech/installation

Thank you Gaël Marziou